# Auto increment value with Fixed String For Each call to the program

Tags: java

This code contains auto increment number that is append to a string... i want it as same..but increment should happen for each call to the program

```
public class Class  //main method contain method calls
{
  private static int count = 0;
  private int jobID;
  private static String name;
  private boolean isFilled;

  public Class1(String title) 
  {
    name = title;
    isFilled = true;
    setJobID(++count);
  }

  public int getJobID()
  {
    return jobID;
  }

  public void setJobID(int jobID)
  {
    this.jobID = jobID;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) // code for auto generation
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
      Class1 tst = new Class1("");
      System.out.print(name);
      System.out.println(tst.getJobID()); 
    }
  }
}
```

Do anyone have a program that contains a Fixed String with an id number (ex:XXX-0000) and the field number  '0000' value should be incremented for each call to the program

Comment: output..: xxx-0001 xxx-02 xxx-03 (XXX is string)

Comment: You have to persist the last used number

Comment: You have to persist the last generated id somewhere (a file, a database, a server on the intranet/internet,...) depending of your use-case.

Comment: tnq for the response...!!   Is there any other case like..     ( but actually i need to increment the id...js like gsa0001 and when i run the program again it should be gsa002 and when i run it again gsa003...so on...!!but the thng is im getting all the values..!!at a time...) in the program itself rather in storage....can it be possible

Answer (score 0):

1.You can pass the 'i' from the for loop to the constructor of the class. And assign it as jobid
2.return type of getJobId  function should be in String since you want to print the string like 'xxx-001'
3.and the datatype of jobID should be String

```
public class Class1  //main method contain method calls`enter code here`
        {
          private static int count = 0;
          private String jobID;
          private static String name="xxx";
          private boolean isFilled;



        public Class1(int jobid) 
        {
            name = title;

           isFilled = true;
            setJobID(jobid);
        }

          public String getJobID()
           {
              return name+jobID;
           }

           public void setJobID(int jobID)
          {
            this.jobID =name+ jobID;
          }





      public static void main(String[] args) // code for auto generation
       {


          for (int i = 0; i < 3
                  ; i++) 
         {

            Class1 tst = new Class1(i);
            System.out.print(name);
            System.out.println(tst.getJobID());


         }
       }
   }
```

Comment: thank you for the response...but actually i need to increment the id...js like gsa0001 and when i run the program again it should be gsa002 and when i run it again gsa003...so on...!!but the thng is im getting all the values..!!at a time...please get me some solution!!

Comment: If you want to increment count each time you run the program,

You have to store your counter variable count into a file or a database table
So every time when execution starts get value from storage-initialize to count -increment and print in method and store to storage after completion of method.
If you do so the variable count will be initialized to new value for each run of the program.